# Custom error not redirecting in web.config

Tags: asp.net

In my web.config file, I have this:

```
<system.web>
     <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/SomePage.aspx" />
</system.web>
```

The problem is that it's not working, I'm still seeing the error pages instead of the custom error page.

What do I need to change?

Comment: The error occurs in an XML Web services?

Comment: In addition, the `SomePage.aspx` page exists in the root of your application?

Comment: yes, SomePage exists.

Comment: And what about my first question?

Comment: is a setting on your machine.config overriding your web.config?

Comment: @YairNevet: no, it's for a page or a directory, not a web service.

Comment: @voddy: no, I don't have a machine.config file in my root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After dealing with this issue on and off for a few days, I've figured out why things aren't working as expected. Check and see what's in your `global.asax` file; mine had the following:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

If the error is handled in the `global.asax` file at the application level, even if there's no actual code in the handler, then the settings in the web.config file are overridden. After I removed this empty block of code, everything worked as expected.